# UICollectionViewCell isn't loaded right after UITabBarController tab change

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uitabbarcontroller, uicollectionviewcell

Okay, so I have part of code where I change `UITabBarController's` tab (to a `UICollectionView`) and right after it I present a popup which has sourceView and sourceRect of a particular cell of that `UICollectionView`.

The problem I have is when I walk through that tab beforehand everything's working fine.

But once I try without selecting that tab, it crashes as the cell isn't loaded. And it sounds fair enough, but how do I solve this?

Doing some 0.1s Dispatch delay seems to be a fishy solution..

```
   tabBarController.selectedViewController = vc 
      if let cell = vc.collectionView?.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)) {
        alertVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = cell
        alertVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = cell.bounds
      } 
   // if statement gets ignored as cv is not yet loaded as it seems
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?(code)

Comment: also share trace of the crash